# what HTML5 video listener can trigger event in the beginning of a video?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

I want to use a listener to trigger a function in the beginning of one video.
Currently I am using:

```
video.addEventListener("play", function);
```

It works in desktop. However in IOS, the function only be triggered When I pause then re-start the video. So, how should I do to make a listener to trigger function just in the beginning of the video? The video may auto play or click to play.

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function)
```

I am not sure is this event won't be send before starting the film so you can use also:

```
 var firstTime = YES;
 video.addEventListener("progress", function() {
                          if (firstTime) {
                              firstTime = NO;
                              // DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE
                          }
                         });
```

For all events which are supported by Safari/Webkit just go to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement. It is very good lecture.